# WPF Databinding fails at binding entire object

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

In the following `DataTemplate`, the first binding doesn't work while the 2nd one works, and I would like to know why.

```
<local:IsEnabledConverter x:Key="isEnabled"/>
<local:Boolean2TextConverter x:Key="txtConverter"/>

<DataTemplate x:Key="fileinfoTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:MyFileInfo}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label x:Name="1stLabel" Content="{Binding Path=Filename}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource isEnabled}}"/>   <--- doesn't work 
        <Label x:Name="2ndLabel" Content="{Binding Path=IfPrint, Converter={StaticResource txtConverter}}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=ckBox}"/>   <--- works
        <CheckBox x:Name="ckBox" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IfPrint}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsValid}" Style="{StaticResource printCkBox}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

IsEnabledConverter:

```
class IsEnabledConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        MyFileInfo f = value as MyFileInfo;
        return  f.IsValid && f.IfPrint;
    }
    //... omit ConvertBack NotImplementedException stuff
}
```

Boolean2TextConverter:

```
class IsEnabledConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        Boolean b = (Boolean)value;
        return b.ToString();
    }
    //similarly omit ConvertBack here
}
```

Code for MyFileInfo:

```
public class MyFileInfo {
   public string IfPrint {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string IsValid {
        get;
        set;
    }
   ...
}
```

**Problem:** When the `CheckBox` is toggled, the 2nd `Label` grays out and shows "false", or becomes normal and shows "true", as it should. However, the first `Label` doesn't change at all; its `IsEnabled` state is supposed be the conjunction of two Booleans, one of which is changed by the `CheckBox`. What is wrong? (note that the `IsEnabledConverter` is called once upon GUI initialization, but not called again when its binding source changes.)

Comment: There seems to be no change notification for the source object itself, only for its properties, like `IfPrint`. You might alternatively use a `MultiBinding` with an `IMultiValueConverter` to bind to the `IsValid` and `IfPrint` properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues here. First you have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the ViewModel `MyFileInfo`. Secondly you have to use `MultiBinding` here. Because I don't think we have some way to trigger updating the target (such as when toggling the CheckBox) if you bind the whole view model to the `IsEnabled` target. So here is how it should be done:

Your view model:

```
public class MyFileInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged {
  bool _ifPrint;
  bool _isValid;
  public bool IfPrint {
    get { return _ifPrint; }
    set {
       if(_ifPrint != value) {
          _ifPrint = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("IfPrint");
       }
    }
  }

  public bool IsValid {
    get { return _isValid; }
    set {
       if(_isValid != value) {
           _isValid = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("IsValid");
       }
    }
  }
  //Implement INotifyPropertyChanged
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected void OnPropertyChanged(string prop){
     var handler = PropertyChanged;
     if(handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
  }
  //.... should do the same for the remaining properties....
  //...
}
```

Here is the converter used for `MultiBinding`, which should implement `IMultiValueConverter` (instead of `IValueConverter`):

```
class IsEnabledConverter : IMultiValueConverter {
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                         System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
    if(values.Length == 2){
      return  (bool) values[0] && (bool) values[1];
    }
    return false;
  }
  //... omit ConvertBack NotImplementedException stuff
}
```

Here is the modifed XAML (to use MultiBinding instead):

```
<Label x:Name="firstLabel" Content="{Binding Path=Filename}">
    <Label.IsEnabled>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource isEnabled}">
            <Binding Path="IsValid"/>
            <Binding Path="IfPrint"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Label.IsEnabled>
</Label>
```

Now one of `IsValid` and `IfPrint` changing will trigger the MultiBinding's Converter. Here you can also bind to `IsChecked` of the CheckBox directly instead of indirectly via `IfPrint`.

**PS:** Note `Name` used in XAML (as well as in codebehind) must not start with number.

Comment: thanks again for your patience and kindness :) could you explain why it is necessary to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for `MultiValue` converter, but not single `ValueConverter`?

Comment: @green when using MVVM pattern, you have always to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Otherwise it may just work **once** (such as when right after loaded).

Comment: but in my original code, it works everytime for the single value binding (text changes between "true" and "false" as the CheckBox toggles) without implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`. just curious why...

Comment: @green well, interesting enough. The rule I said is in fact true. Normally we will have to change the properties using code, then the `INotifyPropetyChanged` will show that it's necessary (without implementing it, changing the properties ***using code*** won't trigger Binding). In this case your `IfPrint` is changed (bound to) via the UI (the CheckBox), so somehow it's notified automatically and makes the consequent Bindings work (in this case the consequent Binding is between the label's Content and the `IfPrint` property)...

Comment: @green This also makes me surprised (never experienced before because I always implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`), +1 for your useful curiosity, it taught me something new :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the instance of `MyFileInfo` does not change while you check/uncheck the `checkbox` hence `IsEnabledConverter`is not getting called.

In order to Enable/Disable your `1stLabel` depending on two properties, either use `MultiValueConverter` or use `MultiDataTrigger` by applying Style to your Label.